# how to make bigger SSTable(MemTable) in cassandra 1.2

Tags: cassandra

At first time (almost default options), Cassandra flush 64MB SSTable.
But I want to this initial SSTable more larger than 64MB.
So, I changed a few cassandra configuration like below (a few times with below config combinations).
But not changed .... And memtable_throughput_in_mb option is deprecated in cassandra 1.2.

memtable_total_space_in_mb: 4096
commitlog_segment_size_in_mb: 32
commitlog_total_space_in_mb: 4096

How to make initial(At the time cassandra flush Memtable to SSTable) 
SSTable size more larger like 128MB or 256MB ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

From [the documentation](http://www.datastax.com/docs/1.0/configuration/storage_configuration#id5) I could find the SSTable size is relative to each column family so you set it using the `sstable_size_in_mb:<value>` option when you create the CF. For example if you wanted your SStable to be 128mb you could issue the following CQL command:

```
ALTER TABLE application.users WITH
    compaction_strategy_options:sstable_size_in_mb:10;
```

Comment: Thanks. But this option only for LeveledCompaction.